# align list items in one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styles

i have this codes & styles in my project:
i want to aling the texts and span style

my default code image like this:

[image]

```css
body {
direction: rtl
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: -100px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  border-radius: 15px;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
     <div>
       <ul>
          <li>
            English<span></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            Spanish<span></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            French<span></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            Russian<span></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            Arabic<span></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            Japanese<span></span>
          </li>
          <li>
            indian<span></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

I want make my list like this image:

[image]

HOW can I align it like image above?
(my body direction is **rtl**)

Comment: Don't you think you need to post your `CSS` code too? And please put it in a `snippet`.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and RTL attribute

Comment: @mplungjan I add it

Comment: Please also add whatever will show the LIs on the screen

Answer (score 2):

change `li { justify-content: space-between; }` to `li { justify-content: flex-end; }`

```css
body {
  direction: rtl
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

span {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      English<span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Spanish<span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      French<span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Russian<span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Arabic<span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      Japanese<span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      indian<span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```